# Find more about a method from rubydoc: Gem::Dependency#pretty_print

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am going through the source code of [Gem::Dependency#pretty_print](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubygems/rubygems/Gem/Dependency#pretty_print-instance_method) method. I don't understand what argument `q` is.

```
def pretty_print q # :nodoc:
  q.group 1, 'Gem::Dependency.new(', ')' do
    q.pp name
    q.text ','
    q.breakable

    q.pp requirement

    q.text ','
    q.breakable

    q.pp type
  end
end
```

My question is, what do I do next from here. I searched `pretty_print` in their [Github repo](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org). They do not have any specs nor any function which uses this method. How can I know what it takes as input `q`? They have defined this method for several other objects.

**Background and more details:**

I am working on a script which reads Gemfile and shows each mentioned Gem with its description. Whenever I am going through the code of any new project which has a long list of Gems, it is difficult to go through each Gem's website and see what the Gem does.

From rubydoc I found how Bundler parses the Gemfile. And came across this method: [Bundler::Dsl#evaluate](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bundler/bundler/Bundler/Dsl#evaluate-class_method)

```
def self.evaluate(gemfile, lockfile, unlock)
  builder = new
  builder.eval_gemfile(gemfile)
  builder.to_definition(lockfile, unlock)
end
```

Here also it is not mentioned what should be passed as `gemfile, lockfile, unlock`. I searched for the method `evaluate` in their Git repo. I found the spec and I learned that I could pass `"Gemfile", nil, true` as the argument.

I mentioned the flow so that if I can get any comments on it and improve.

Comment: My one suggestion is a little bit too much but it might help.. byebug or put a debug point in all the function definitions of pretty print .. try basic bundler commands in any example rails project `bundle install` or `bundle exec rails s` .. see if it hits the function definition ... that might give you an idea what q is in pretty print.. its just a suggestion not a definitive answer and also you would have to put local path of bundler in your rails gem file for debgging purposes

Comment: @PriyankKapadia yeah it is one of the options. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pretty_print` method is going to be used by `pp`.

By defining `pretty_print` we can customize the output of `pp` as per their [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html).